# How to create user specific file with unique name in the reducer phase of Hadoop Map Reduce Framework(In Python))

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-streaming

I have written one code for the reducer which will read the output from the mapper. And then It will create a new file with the key name And all the values corresponding to same key will be stored into one file.

**My code is:**

```
!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

last_key      = None              #initialize these variables

for input_line in sys.stdin:

    input_line = input_line.strip()
    data = input_line.split("\t") 
    this_key = data[0]
    if len(data) == 2:
        value = data[1]
    else:
        value = None
    if last_key == this_key:
        if value:
            fp.write('{0}\n'.format(value))
    else:
        if last_key:
            fp.close()
            fp = open('%s.txt' %this_key,'a')
            if value:
                fp.write('{0}\n'.format(value))
        if not last_key:
            fp = open('%s.txt' %this_key,'a')
            if value:
                fp.write('{0}\n'.format(value))
        last_key = this_key
```

But It is not creating any file.

So, My question is what function should I need to use to create new files into HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

There are no straightforward solution to achieve this.You may follow below approaches to achieve this using Mapreduce:

Approach 1: Using partitioner

1. Find out unique number of files.e.g. count unique number of '%this_key%' in file.
2. Set number of reducer to previous step result in mapreduce driver [each file per reducer].
3. Use partitioner to send the map-output to particular reducer.
4. Reducer emit only %value%.
5. At the end of job you will have same key value per file and you might rename reducer output files.

Approach 2: if number of files are very less then use [MultipleOutputs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html) .

Comment: But I have huge number of keys around 105074.

As per my requirement I need separate files for each key. So, If I use the 1st approach then I need 105074 reducer .

Comment: that's correct. you may categorize your keys into multiple group then use approach 1 with lesser numbe of reducer.

Comment: Yes, 
Beacause the situation is that in that big file each line is representing like:

Timestamp   **longitude latitude pcpn**

for each timestamp there are 2 lakhs of value is there. here timestamp is the key. 

So, now for each time u need make an graph where at a particular longitude and latitude u will put a colour based on pcpn value.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the approach 1.

Actually I am very much new in python as well as in hadoop .So, I did not know how to do all these process.

1.Set number of reducer to previous step result in mapreduce driver [each file per reducer].
2.Use partitioner to send the map-output to particular reducer.

So, could you please explain it more  or send me some links where i can find some examples.

Comment: I would suggest you to learn hadoop then try to solve this problem.

Comment: yes you are correct but actually I am doing some internship and I have only 2 wks lft ,so I don't have that much time to learn it properly in 2 weeks.
So, if you have some links where I can see some examples could you please send it to me so that I can grab it quickly.

ANd one more thing is that in second approach you have send me a link of "Multiple Outputs" But it is for Java program I think. But I am doing all my jobs in python.

So, It would be very helpful if u send me any links, it should be of python programming

Comment: this may help you: http://ce.sysu.edu.cn/hope/UploadFiles/Education/2011/10/201110221516245419.pdf